# Can a single EntityManager (Hibernate) participate in multiple concurrent transactions?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jta, hibernate-entitymanager

Is there a way one EntityManager can participate smoothely in multiple concurrent transactions?

Well, not that concurrent. Something like:

1. Start tx 1
2. Do stuff in tx 1
3. Start tx 2
4. Do stuff in tx 2
5. Commit tx 2
6. Join tx 1 back
7. Do stuff in tx 1
8. Commit tx 1

with steps followed one by one not overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Separate** transactions? No, it can not.

Attempting to call [EntityTransaction.begin()](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/ejb3-api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html#begin()) on a currently active transaction (which is what you would have to do, diretly or indirectly) will result in `IllegalStateException` being thrown.

Unit of work / transaction scope concepts are explained in detail in the [Hibernate EntityManager manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/transactions.html).